# AC_PROG_CC and paths that contain spaces

Tags: windows, gcc, autoconf

My `configure.ac` contains the following fragment:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([gcc],
            [C compiler],
            [CC="$withval"])
AC_PROG_CC
```

However, when I try to pass a path that contains spaces via `--with-gcc`, I get the following error:

```
configure:2377: checking for gcc
configure:2404: result: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe"
configure:2633: checking for C compiler version
configure:2642: "c:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2013.2.0.0\mingw\bin\gcc.exe" --version >&5
./configure: line 2644: "c:\Program: No such file or directory
configure:2653: $? = 127
```

Is there some way to make `AC_PROG_CC` not die when `CC` is set to a path that contains spaces?

Comment: Your `AC_ARG_WITH` is unnecessary.  The `configure` script can be run as `./configure CC=...`.  I don't know if that will fix your problem or not.  Possibly using a [short path name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) might though.

Comment: @ldav1s Using a short path name is a cool idea, thanks. I'll try that.